# How to define BigQuery schema using Standard SQL?

Tags: python, schema, google-bigquery

I'd like to use BigQuery Standard SQL in a new project, however I am not able to find any examples on how to define the schema, everything points at Legacy SQL. In particular, I want to use `ARRAY` and `STRUCT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to create a table in BigQuery is by using the API calls. There is no CREATE table syntax.

Creating a table

BigQuery offers various ways to create a new table [as detailed here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#bigquery-create-table-python):

- You can create an empty table by using the command line tool's bq mk command or by using the BigQuery API tables.insert() method.
- You can load a table from a CSV or JSON data file (compressed or uncompressed), from an Avro file, or from a Cloud Datastore backup.
- You can create a table from a query result.
- You can copy a table
- You can define a table over a file in Cloud Storage
- you can use Standard SQL types when you define your table schema (see Elliotts answer) and there is a tichet about to update in docs as well. Vote/star [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36168576).

lots of [Python samples are on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/snippets.py) simple as:

```
def create_table(dataset_name, table_name, project=None):
    """Creates a simple table in the given dataset.
    If no project is specified, then the currently active project is used.
    """
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project=project)
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)

    if not dataset.exists():
        print('Dataset {} does not exist.'.format(dataset_name))
        return

    table = dataset.table(table_name)

    # Set the table schema
    table.schema = (
        bigquery.SchemaField('Name', 'STRING'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Age', 'INTEGER'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Weight', 'FLOAT'),
    )

    table.create()

    print('Created table {} in dataset {}.'.format(table_name, dataset_name))
```

Comment: Thanks for more pointers, but this example doesn't cover use of `STRUCT` or `ARRAY` types. I've checked [the implementation of `bigquery.SchemaField`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/44b4d50e59f5d5ace419dcfbe2b04c2e07cadc57/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/schema.py#L24-L26), and the docs clearly are about Legacy SQL.

Comment: You are confused a little bit. So SQL is only used for queries not for defining tables. When you create table you need to use the types listed there, which is neither Legacy nor Standard SQL it's API definition of field type. You can go ahead and use the types as listed there in your JSON when you define your tables, and when you write Standard SQL queries you can simply use as Struct or Array the RECORD or REPEATED defined field types.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This make sense, however I think it's something that should be documented more specifically. It's enough that as a new user, I already have to be aware of two different Language versions.

Comment: you can submit feedback on every google page, use those

Answer (score 2):

You can create a table with a schema that uses standard SQL types. Here is an example of a valid schema:

```
{
  "a": "ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING>>",
  "b": "STRUCT<z DATE>",
  "c": "INT64"
}
```

If you put this in a file such as `sample_schema.json`, you can create a table from it using `bq mk`:

```
bq mk --schema sample_schema.json -t your_dataset.YourTableName
```

Outside of the `bq` client, the `tables.insert` API also supports standard SQL type names.

Comment: Is this an undocumented feature? It would simply won't pass any JSON validation implemented in librarys.

Comment: I had meant to quote the `INT64`; is that what you are referring to? Aside from that, the values are just strings.

Comment: yep, but is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be. I filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36168576.

Comment: Ah, interesting! And what do the top level keys (`a`, `b` & `c`) mean here?

Comment: Those are the names of the top level columns in the table (you can substitute whichever names and types you would like).