# specifying nested/record type for schema with bq command line

Tags: google-bigquery

The documentation states that you can specify the schema on the command line when you load. This works fine for flat schemas, i.e name:string,gender:string,count:integer.  Can you specify the mode as well?
If you want a field to be say repeatable, do we need to use a JSON file to specify that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/42746326/5221944, more specifically - answer for that question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42763270/5221944

Comment: Thank you  Mikhail,  I was wondering if there was a way to specify the schema without putting it into a file like the examples...something like bq mk -t <project-id>:<dataset-id>.<table> foo:string,bar:"ARRAY of INTS"....I can put the schema in a JSON file and that works fine...just wanted to skip that step if possible....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortcut text representation of schema has only enough support for flat schemas without RECORD structure and without REPEATED fields. You will have to use file with JSON schema for those.

Comment: Arrh, the original post had multiple questions - some of them have answer "No" ("Can you specify the mode as well") and some "Yes" ("do we need to use a JSON file"), so I just removed the "The answer is No/Yes" part :)